# Can Find the error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, identifier

So my Java online class, i have to include variables to and provide set and get methods to get the name of  course's instructor, and display the message: welcome to the grade book for: and this course is presented by:

Class GradeBook:

```
public class GradeBook
{
    private String courseName;
    public String courseTeacher;

    public GradeBook( String name, String teacher )
    {
        courseName = name;
        courseTeacher = teacher;
    }

    public void setCourseName( String name )
    {
        courseName = name;
    }

    public String getCourseName()
    {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseTeacher( String teacher )
    {
        courseTeacher = teacher;
    }

    public String getcourseTeacher()
    {
        return courseTeacher;
    }

    public void displayMessage()
    {
        System.out.printf( " Welcome to the grade book for:/n%s!\n" ,         getCourseName() , "This course is presented by: \n%s\n!" ,getCourseTeacher() );
    }

}
```

Main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeBookTest
{
    public static void main( String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        GradeBook myGradeBook = new GradeBook( "Cs101","Ciro" );

        System.out.println( "Please enter the course name:" );
        String theName = input.nextLine();
        myGradeBook.setCourseName( theName );

        System.out.println( "Please enter instructor name:" );
        String theTeacher = input.nextLine();
        myGradeBook.setCourseTeacher( theTeacher );

        System.out.println();
        myGradeBook.displayMessage();
    }
}
```

error:

```
cannot find symbol method getCourseTeacher()      GradeBook      line 38
```

Comment: JaVa Is CaSe SeNsItIvE.

Answer (score 4):

Java is case-sensitive, so `getcourseTeacher` should be `getCourseTeacher` (with a capital `C`) in the method definition:

```
public String getcourseTeacher()
                 ^ THIS
```

Comment: Wow i looking for lower case letter but in the wrong place, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to indicate which line is 38th line that gives error. Second of all check your SETTER AND GETTER. In GradeBook constructor you indicate it as courseTeacher so your setter and getter are supposed to be "setCourseTeacher" and "getCourseTeacher".